# Delete multiple entries in SQL database table. Right query?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have the following table:

```
-----------------
| Movie | Genre |
-----------------
| A     | Horror |
-----------------
| A     | Thiller |
-----------------
| B     | Comedy |
-----------------
| C     | Drama |
-----------------
| D     | Horror |
 ....
```

I want to delete `Movies` that are `Horror`. But I know that if I simply say

```
delete * where genre='Horror'
```

that will be a wrong query because 1 movie remains - `A` - because it is also a `Thiller`.

```
| A     | Thiller |
```

but I want to get rid of `A`.

**What query should I write?**
I am new to SQL and relational db theory but I guess that maybe we should first take cross product or join or smth of that table.

DBMS: MySQL or Oracle.

Comment: You might want to add the DBMS you are using. Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Are you really using MySQL **and** Oracle?

Comment: no yet. I am just doing to choose one of them.

Comment: If you are looking for a *free* database, you should seriously consider Postgres instead of MySQL. If you don't care about the money, go for Oracle.

Comment: Are there indexes on that table?  and i agree with a_horse_with_no_name here PostgreSQL/Oracle database are more mature database vs MySQL with an better planner... MySQL becomes better now because this is an product off Oracle but MySQL community version won't be better then Oracle database that is for sure..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete from movies
where movie in (select movie
                from movies
                where genre = 'Horror');
```

The above query works for Oracle (and Postgres and SQL Server and DB2 and Firebird and H2 and HSQLDB and ...) but not for MySQL.

For MySQL it would need to be rewritten as a join:

```
delete movies
from movies 
  join movies m2 on movies.movie = m2.movie
where m2.genre = 'Horror';
```

Comment: It won't work on MySQL (not sure about other DBMSs).

Comment: @AlexanderKouznetsov: I know. It's one of the many really stupid limitations of MySQL (it does work on all other DBMS as far as I know). But Oleksandra hasn't which DBMS she/he is using. Therefor the answer can only use standard SQL.

Comment: Actually the structure in the question is wrong. There couldn't be such question in normalized db. And it's not a limitation. It's the way MySql runs queries (and subqueries as well))))

Comment: @Oleksandra If you don't have structure yet, you'd better change it and have it normalized. If structure exists you need to do like the following. 1. Create temp table. 2. Fill temp table like this INSERT INTO temp(movie) SELECT movie FROM film WHERE genre='Horror'. 3. Delete films DELETE FROM film WHERE movie (SELECT movie FROM temp) 4. Clean or drop temp table

Comment: @Oleksandra you need create 3 tables 1. Movies table (movie_id, movie_name). 2. Genres table (genre_id, genre_name) 3. Links between movies and genres (movie_id,genre_id). So you'll be able to delete films with one query (maybe one more query will be needed to cleanup links)

Comment: @Oleksandra because MySQL does not allow the table to be deleted from to be used in a sub-query

Comment: @AlexanderKouznetsov: I do agree that the model should be normalized, but the delete can be done in MySQL with a single statement as well despite the stupid sub-query limitations.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a limitation in DELETE that jou can not join or subquery the same table you are deleting from. But if you wrap the required ids in another subquery, it will work:

```
DELETE FROM m 
USING movies m 
JOIN (
  SELECT Movie
  FROM movies
  WHERE Genre = 'Horror'
) m2:
```